# What is a nester?

Tags: meaning

> The family lifecycle (FLC) idea has been particularly threatened. The FLC traces the
>   development of a person’s life along a path from young and single, to married with no
>   children, married with young children, married couples with older children, older married
>   couples with no children at home, empty **nesters** still in employment, retired empty **nester**
>   couples, to sole survivor working or not working. Life for many, if not most people, does not
>   follow this path. It fails to take account of the many and varied life choices that people make:
>   some people never marry, others marry late, there are also childless couples, gay and lesbian
>   partnerships, extended families, single-parent households and divorced couples.

The word "nester" seems odd to me. I don't know if it is person or place (used with empty). [Witionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nester) and [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nester)'s definitions also do not seem to fit in this context. Then, what is it, especially in US English as I think the text is in American English?

Comment: [empty nester](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empty%20nester)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the following people or places?

> The FLC traces the development of **a person’s** life along a path from
>
> *young and single, to
>
>   married with no children,
>
>   married with young children,
>
>   married couples with older children,
>
>   older married couples with no children at home*....

To that list is added

> *empty nesters still in employment,
>
>   retired empty nester couples, to
>
>   sole survivor working or not working*.

Note that *[empty nester](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=empty+nester)* is a compound word describing a person (not a place, I hope you can see)...

...so "nester" is not a "technical"  or widely used term used to describe a person in terms of the life cycle of a human being. A "nester" could refer to a person who exhibits certain properties, such as Urban Dictionary's definitions 2 and 4.

Sometimes each part of a compound word is not used on its own to the same  extent that the complete compound word is used, as in *staple remover*. Everybody knows what this is and uses it  but *remover* is not used as often by itself, in American English at least.

Comment: The origin of the term is the "empty nest syndrome" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_nest_syndrome in which parents feel depressed when their children have grown up and left home.